# Concise FULLTEXT Search

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search, myisam

I've been trying to find some help on using MySQL's FULLTEXT search. I realise that this has been discussed to death, but I can't quite understand how to get a concise set of results.

I have a MyISAM table of say 500,000 products with a FULLTEXT index setup on the "product_name" table.

A basic query would be:

```
SELECT * from products MATCH(product_name) AGAINST ("coffee table") AS relevance 
WHERE MATCH(product_name) AGAINST ("coffee table").
```

I got a list of a few hundred products that relate to either coffee or tables. This wasn't specific enough and meant that useful results were cluttered with too many other items.

I altered my query to use MATCH to give a relevance to each result, and then used LIKE to perform the actual query.

```
SELECT * from products MATCH(product_name) AGAINST ("coffee table") AS relevance 
WHERE ((product_name like "%coffee%" AND product_name like "%table%") or product_name like "%coffee table%")
```

This idea I got from seeing how Wordpress performs a search. This worked well until someone performs a search with more specific keywords. A real-world example was a search for "Nike blazer low premium vintage". In this case, there were no results (whereas the first method using MATCH returned hundreds)

I know I can use IN BOOLEAN MODE, but many users won't know to use the +/- operators to alter their query. I'm yet to work out how I should use the HAVING clause to limit results.

Also, due to this being shared hosting, I am unable to alter the default min word length - which means missing keywords like the colour "red" or the brand-name "GAP" for example.

I have read a little into creating a keyword index table, but have not found suitable references for this.

Can someone please offer a solution where I can use a product search term (as entered by Joe Public) that will give a concise set of results. Thanks

Comment: Would you like `Nike blazer low premium vintage` to return something? Also, if I understand correctly, you want to match as many words as possible, and not take into account the built-in relevance computed by fulltext, right?

Comment: Mathieu - thanks for your reply. I would like it to return results, but not for each keyword individually as that has too many. I also do an ORDER BY on the MATCH/relevance and return the top results. The number it generates will vary with the number of keywords I assume?

Comment: The relevance is no only based on the number of keywords, but on the relevance of each keywords: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/full-text-search.html

Comment: OK, well I think that is OK. I sort by relevance and return the top results - so that is all I need for this search I think. The question is still how to get the right amount of results - MATCH doesn't return anything for my example, and LIKE returns too many

Comment: Then if you don't want to use the default behavior, and want to match *as much keywords as possible*, why don't you use Boolean search? The default operator is `OR` and the relevance will be the number of matched keywords.

Comment: This does seem better. So I guess I'd want to set the score to match say at least 50% of the keywords? "having relevance > floor(count(keywords)*0.5"

Comment: Yes exactly, that could work.

Comment: This seems to work, although the stopwords and minimum length words need to be removed before searching otherwise it breaks. Match also seems to ignore plurals in boolean mode and I think putting a * around each word is a bad idea. As far as my other method (MATCH + LIKE) - would this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done more research and as many people have said, it's not a good solution for "human" like searching - one example is how it handles word plurals (car / cars). I looked at Apache Lucene but it's beyond my ability to setup and configure.

For the moment, the "solution" has been to stick with `IN BOOLEAN MODE` (as Mathieu also suggested).